# Python file Reading

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I would like to read the following text from a file 10 lines in a batch. With each value from lines arriving in specific variable as I would like to plot them later on in a continuous manner. Here is the file data format:

```
Xus level 5 : var1 = 885775, var2 = 50
Xus level 4 : var1 = 885710, var2 = 25
Xus level 3 : var1 = 885705, var2 = 25
Xus level 2 : var1 = 885640, var2 = 100
Xus level 1 : var1 = 885610, var2 = 275
Yus level 1 : var3 = 885510, var4 = 6875
Yus level 2 : var3 = 885505, var4 = 500
Yus level 3 : var3 = 885500, var4 = 225
Yus level 4 : var3 = 885465, var4 = 25
Yus level 5 : var3 = 885460, var4 = 100
... (continue above format with changed values...)
```

I would like to read this in a python code. store the values in some variables then plot the 10 lines at one go then in some while loop with some sleep, i would read other 10 lines plot them, and then repeat the stuff till the end of file.

Comment: Why tag it with sed and awk if you want to do it in python???

Comment: where is your code showing your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Change your file name.txt to the name of your file

```
# open your file (Your file name.txt is the file name in read mode (r))
file = open(Your file name.txt", "r")
# for each line in Your File
for line in file:
# Split each word that is inbetween commers into seperate variables
    details =line.split(", ")
    Level1 = details[0]
    Level2 = details[1]
```

This will Save in Level1

```
Yus level{number} : var1 = {number}
```

And in Level2

```
var2=50
```

Don't know how to  get rid of `Yus level '1'`

And it will only do one at a time, Modify it as you wish.

Comment: @LeBlue
yours works allot better than mine, but would there not be a , after words[4]

Comment: Thanks. What about the thing that I want to read 10 lines, then once I'm done with the 10 lines, I want to read the 10 next lines. This is just a loop on each line, I want to read it but once I read 10 lines I will do some processing then I will continue the same again. Get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just split each line by space an get the columns by index:

```
# open file
file = open("filename", "r")

# for each line the file 'filename'
for line in file:

    # split the line in between spaces:
    words = line.split(" ")

    # get the columns by position:
    level = words[2]
    var_name_1 = words[4] 
    var_value_1 = words[6].split(",")[0] # get rid of ,
    # etc

    # do something here ...
    # perhaps add to a list:
    # array_value_1.append(var_value_1)
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the thing that I want to read 10 lines, then once I'm done with the 10 lines, I want to read the 10 next lines. This is just a loop on each line, I want to read it but once I read 10 lines I will do some processing then I will continue the same again. Get it ?